# How to export data from website to csv file using Javascript?

Tags: node.js, csv, export-to-csv

I saw this code from a website and apparently it works on other people even for my friend but not for me. I am using Nodejs and express. Am i doing it wrongly or did i miss out any important parts? After the button was clicked, that was no pop out of the file directory or anything and there is no error to be seen as well.

This are the codes from the script.

```
<script>
        function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
            var csvFile;
            var downloadLink;
            //var charset = "UTF-8";

            // CSV File
            csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

            // download link
            downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            // file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;

            // create link to file
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

            // hide download link
            downloadLink.style.display = "";

            // add link to DOM
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            // click download link
            downloadLink.click();
        }

        function exportData(html,filename) {
            var csv = [];
            var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

            for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
                var rows = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                for (var j=0; j<cols.length; j++) {
                    if (j == 7) {
                        row.push("'" + cols[j].innerText + "'");
                    } 
                    else if (j == 2){
                        row.push("'" + cols[j].innerText + "'");
                    } 
                    else {
                        row.push(cols[j].innerText);
                    }
                }

                csv.push(row.join(","));
            }

            // download csv file
            downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);

        }
    </script>
```

This are the codes from the design part.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="exportBtn" onclick="exportData(null,'scrapedData.csv')">导出</button>
```

Comment: which browser do u use? in case of `safari`, u could not be able to download.
I recommend u to use `FileSaver.js`'s `saveAs()` function.

Comment: Im using google chrome

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example is working

```js
        function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
            var csvFile;
            var downloadLink;

            // CSV File
            csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

            // download link
            downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            // file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;

            // create link to file
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

            // hide download link
            downloadLink.style.display = "";

            // add link to DOM
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            // click download link
            downloadLink.click();
        }

        function exportData(html,filename) {
            var csv = [];           

            csv.push('a');
            csv.push('b');
            csv.push('c');
            csv.push('d');
            csv.push('e');
            
            // download csv file
            downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);

        }
```

```html
<button onClick="exportData(null, 'testCSV.csv')">download</button>
```